# Does Azure Storage failover and failback need two replications?

Tags: cloud, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

If I have an Azure Storage with GRS, and the WUS is primary and EUS is secondary.
Then if I need to do a customer failover, what will happen is that WUS is deleted, EUS becomes primary.
For example, after the issue in WUS has fixed, how many replications do I need to bring back to the state that WUS is primary and EUS is secondary?

Based on what I learned from the official document in Microsoft Learn. I think the process is like this:

1. Change to GRS again. There will be a **replication** happen that transfer all data in EUS to WUS.
   After this we have: WUS(secondary) + EUS(primary)
2. Failback to WUS. We will have: WUS(LRS) + EUS(deleted)
3. Change to GRS again. There will be another **replication** happen that transfer all data in WUS to EUS.
   After this we have: WUS(primary) + EUS(secondary)

So, my question is that do we need to twice replications in order to change back to "primary is WUS, secondary is EUS" state? Because this since to be rather expensive as you need to transfer all data twice and it is time consuming, costly a lot.

This is a question on how Azure Storage works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there would be 2 replications required and the process [would work as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/redundancy-migration?tabs=portal) .

[Azure storage disaster recovery planning and failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance)

We currently have Planned Failover in private preview which will allow customers to test the Failover work flow while keeping geo-redundancy. As a result, there is no need to re-enable geo redundancy after each failover and failback operation. This table highlights the key differences between Customer Managed Failover (currently GA) and Planned Failover (currently in planned state ).

[image]